# What npm package to use for unit testing POST request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, express

It will have to have the option to set the req.params of POST request.

`supertest` package doesn't provide this or it is not well documented to be clear it does.

Comment: supertest just uses superagent in the background so it should work fine, did you try using it or just scan the docs? If you did try using it then post your code

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing an express application, supertest supports POST as well as most other HTTP methods. The express `req.params` is populated by the path portion of the URL, so you would do something like

```
var app = require('./my-app')
var request = require('supertest')(app)

request.post('/some/path/req/params/is/here?some=query')
  .send({some: 'body'})
  .expect(200)
  .end(function (error, res) {
    assert(res.body.something === 'value')
  })
```

Comment: This is not true, `req.query` is populated by the url parameters. I need a way to populate `req.params`.

Comment: `req.query` comes from the query string (the part after the `?`). `req.params` comes from the URL path part itself (before the `?`) and is based on using placeholders in the express route path like `app.post('/api/users/:id')` in which case the URL `/api/users/42` would result in `req.params.id` being `"42"`.

Comment: If you want to avoid wasting everyone's time, post a code snippet, as the stackoverflow guidelines suggest, and we can help you specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can with super test, since it has the same actions as [superagent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent), this is an example:

```
request
  .post('/api/pet')
  .send({ name: 'Manny', species: 'cat' })
  .set('X-API-Key', 'foobar')
  .set('Accept', 'application/json')
  .end(function(err, res){
    // Calling the end function will send the request 
  });
```

https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest

> By default sending strings will set the Content-Type to
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multiple calls will be concatenated
>   with &, here resulting in name=tj&pet=tobi:

```
request.post('/user')
    .send('name=tj')
    .send('pet=tobi')
    .end(callback);
```

Comment: req.param is empty. This doesn't help. What is `set('X-API-Key', 'foobar')` used for ? I need to send parameters with application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Comment: @MatkoKlaic I saw your other question and I would need to know how are you defining your route handler in express, since `req.params` is populated automatically from the endpoint definition

Comment: @MatkoKlaic I think you're reading to literally, it's just an example of what you can do. :) If you read the superagent documentation you can see how to send `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: My /api/token is set to work with node-oauth2-server.

Comment: Do I have to used bodyParser ?

Comment: That was it. body-parser was missing. He populates the req.params.

Answer (score 0):

The [supertest docs](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest) say:

> Anything you can do with superagent, you can do with supertest

Therefore, the following should work fine:

```
request(app)
.post('/')
.query({format: 'json'})
.expect(....)
```